# In flink self-defined evictor, how to get the newest watermark

Tags: java, apache-flink

Self-defined evictor has override function `evictBefore`, one of its parameters is `EvictorContext`. I find this class has a function `getCurrentWatermark()`, but after I test, I find this function can not get the newest watermark, but the watermark before the newest watermark, seems this function didn't upgrade in time.

How can I solve the problem and get the newest watermark in self-defined evictor? Thanks a lot and sorry for my poor English!

Comment: I checked the implementation of EvictorContext, and I believe it is correct. Perhaps there is some misunderstanding about how watermarks are updated, and the meaning of "current watermark". How did you test this?

Comment: I think the current watermark is the max timestamp of elements, isn't it?(or more exactly need to subtract delay time for elements out of orderness, then substract 1 ms) What I want to implement is to use evictor to evict elements that are out of window size in the global window. I defined cutOff = currentWatermark - windowSize. if elements's timestamp < cutOff, this elements will be evict. And today I find an existed evictor "TimeEvictor" has done this work. So my problem has a solution by this.

Comment: But I still have some confusion. In the implementation of TimeEvictor, I find it use the getMaxTimestamp funcition that search the max timestamp by iterator. Why do not use the getCurrentWatermark() to avoid search all the elements in the window?

Comment: @DavidAnderson I have two comments above, can you have a look, thank you very much!

Comment: Honestly, I've never seen a case where using a custom evictor was a good idea. It always leads to a convoluted, difficult to test (and difficult to maintain) implementation. Have you considered using a process function (or, depending on the use case, Flink SQL) instead?

Comment: @DavidAnderson ok, i’ll have a try, thank you a lot.